# Magento 2: Invalid header value detected

Tags: magento2, product, url, http-header

On opening a certain product page, we are getting the following error

```
"exception":"[object] (Zend\\Http\\Header\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Invalid header value detected at /app/6l7tzyfknugxk/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php:53)"
```

We cannot find anything wrong in the product info in the admin.

Comment: Did you install any new modules? This can probably cause problems, for example an older version of LiteMage

Comment: We don't have Litemage installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the names of your products, maybe it contains special characters, or your header in the product contains some special characters.

Comment: Is there any way to debug this? As far as I know headers are validated in Zend's GenericHeader class. But we cannot override it to add logs.

Comment: We just removed all the content of the product and added back and it resolved the issue. I think there were invisible spaces added while creating the product. For someone who is facing this I recommend to create the product again,

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to debug, and the reasons can be different.

Go to:

> vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php:53

Add **var_dump** in this part:

```php
if (! HeaderValue::isValid($parts[1])) {
    var_dump($parts[1]);
    throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('Invalid header value detected');
}
```

Check what exactly is not correct and fix it.

In my case, it was empty char at the end string of *base_url*